# My exe connector sudden stop running on a windows machine. (Build with c# in visual studio)

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created an service application in visual studio using c# and was working fine on windows machine but sudden one day it stops working. when i look into the event viewer i got this log from there

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
<Level>2</Level> 
<Task>0</Task> 
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-02-13T15:09:51.945244700Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>32886</EventRecordID> 
<Channel>Application</Channel> 
<Computer>asus</Computer> 
<Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Application: sage50-uk-2019-v25.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.InvalidCastException at sage50_uk_2019_v25.Service1..cctor() Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException at sage50_uk_2019_v25.Service1..ctor() at sage50_uk_2019_v25.Program.Main(System.String[])</Data>
```

I have gone through many resolution over the web but nothing useful for my situation.
Note: On other machines its still working. So i guess something has happened on the machine or windows OS.

Code for my main function on program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sage50_UK_v26_2_136_0
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Service1 myService = new Service1();
            myService.OnDebug();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}
```

Constructor for the service class:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EventHandler handler = initApp;
        handler?.Invoke(this, null);
    }

    public void initApp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                // adding application into startup program
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkApp = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
                rkApp.SetValue(applicationName, "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");
                deQueue(sender, e);
                addTimer();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToLogFile("SDO Generated the Following Error: \n\n" + ex.Message);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pauseThreadInMilliSeconds);
                initApp(sender, e);
            }

            // loop while we're pending and the user is retrying
        } while (companyName == "" || apiKey == "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the description.  You have an invalid Cast exception in the constructor for the `Service1` class (called from the `Main` function)

Comment: yes i have seen that. have declared my variables according their types

Comment: And, the constructor for the `Service1` class looks like...?

Comment: @Flydog57 added service class code too. its not completed but i guess it may help